# jquery add new divs that show input fields after select menu

Tags: jquery, element, addition, forms

For each user, there are several references. Each reference might have different attributes. So I want the user to select the reference attribute first, then for that attribute input fields become visible. If a user has multiple references, he might be able to add a new reference by simply clicking the add button and a new selection appears, and so on.

I tried to do it with javascript but there was some minor problems. I found a rather simple jQuery solution for handling selection:

HTML

```
<form>
    <select id="sel">
        <option value="">- select -</option>
        <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option2">Option 2</option>          
    </select>
    <input type="text" class="option1" /><span>Textbox label 1</span>
    <input type="text" class="option2" /><span>Textbox label 2</span>
    <input type="text" class="option2" /><span>Textbox label 2</span>
    <input type="text" class="option2" /><span>Textbox label 2</span>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $('#sel').change(function() {
        $("input").hide().filter("." + $(this).find("option:selected").val()).show();
    });
    $("input").focus(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeIn(1000);
    }).blur(function() {
        $(this).next("span").fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
input {
    display:none;
}
span {
    display:none;
}
```

and then adding new divs..

```
var inival=1;
function addNew(){
    var newArea = add_New_Element();
    var htcontents = "<select id="sel">"+
        "<option value="">- select -</option>"+
        "<option value="option1">Option 1</option>"+
        "<option value="option2">Option 2</option>"  +        
    "</select>"+
    "<input type="text" class="option1" /><span>Textbox label 1</span>"+
    "<input type="text" class="option2" /><span>Textbox label 2</span>"+
    "<input type="text" class="option2" /><span>Textbox label 2</span>"+
    "<input type="text" class="option2" /><span>Textbox label 2</span>"; 
    document.getElementById(newArea).innerHTML = htcontents;            
}

function add_New_Element() {
    inival=inival+1; 
    var ni = document.getElementById('area');
    var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
    var divIdName = 'Div #'+ inival;
    newdiv.setAttribute('id',divIdName);
    ni.appendChild(newdiv);
    return divIdName;
}

function addNew();
```

But you might see, this is a very long solution. I guess there is more efficient and shorter solutions. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why are you manually creating and appending elements when you claim to be using jQuery?

Comment: On multiple lines your use double quotations as part of html where the string is enclosed in double quotes. `"<input type="text" ...`

Comment: hi Sorpigal, it is because i do not know jQuery.

Comment: if you may, you may show an example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it is not my solution, it might help other people

http://jsfiddle.net/MXXXT/16/

original answer is belonging to Jeff